# Prove $A = \{x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots ) \mid |x_k| \leq M \ \text{for all $k$ , for some positive number $M$}\}$ is open in uniform topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ (countably infinite product of $\mathbb{R}$) with the uniform metric.

Let $A$ be the set of infinite bounded sequences of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $$A = \{x = (x_1, x_2, \dots ) \mid |x_k| \leq M \ \text{for all $k$ , for some positive number $M$}\}$$

Consider the metric $d(x,y) = \mathop{\text{sup }}_k \{\text{min}\{|x_k-y_k|, 1\}\}$.

I want to prove $A$ is open in the topology generated by $d$ (uniform topology).

MY ATTEMPT:

We want to show that there must exist some $r>0$ such that $B_d(x,r) \subset A$.

Let $y = (y_k) \in B_d(x,r) \implies d(x,y)<r$. We know that $d(x,y) \leq 1$.

So, we can take $r =\frac{1}{2}$ (because we have to choose a $r>0$ ) such that $B_d(x, \frac{1}{2}) \subset A$. Assume $y \in B_d(x, \frac{1}{2})$, then $d(x, y) < \frac{1}{2}$, hence $$\text{sup } \{\text{min } |x_k - y_k|,1\}\}< \frac{1}{2}$$ hence,    $\text{min } \{ |x_k - y_k|,1\}< \frac{1}{2}$ iff $|x_k -y_k| < \frac{1}{2}$, hence $|y_k| < M + \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $y \in A$, hence $B_d(x,r) \subset A$ with $r = \frac{1}{2}$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Open relative to what space? For example, the metric $d$ is also a metric in the space $\mathcal{N}$  of all numerical sequences $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow{C}$. $A\subset \mathcal{N}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz $\mathbb{R} ^\omega$ with the uniform metric. I have edited my post.